# What is the purpose of gcloud config set container/cluster cluster_name?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two GKE clusters: c1, c2,

I use `gcloud config set container/cluster c1` to set the default cluster to c1, after that I run `kubectl run`, seems the new pods still created in c2.

how can i switch to c2? and what is the purpose of `gcloud config set container/cluster cluster_name`?

Answer (score 1):

The `gcloud container cluster` commands are for administrating your clusters from a GCP perspective, e.g. adding another node-pool for a GKE kubernetes cluster using the [node-pools create command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create).

Controlling which cluster is used for kubectl is done via .kube/config file which has a so called `current-context`. There is the [kubectx/kubens project](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) that provides some nice helpers to allow switching between clusters (and namespaces) more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple clusters, you can set a default cluster for the kubectl command-line tool.

To set a default cluster for gcloud commands, run the following command:

gcloud config set container/cluster CLUSTER_NAME